# Android Wallpaper Animation

Tags: android, android-animation, live-wallpaper

I won't create wallpaper-application but have one problem.

Please tell me how add `ImageView` or another element in android wallpaper-application to create frame animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure that live wallpapers can't use activities, but If you want to have an animation, you can always draw your objects on a Canvas or using OpenGL. For detailed example, see this:
http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2010/02/01/live-wallpapers-with-android-sdk-2-1.html